# Riding an elephant on a UK road

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic, animals

If I needed to move an elephant from Warrington to Peterborough, would I be able to ride it there?

I know it is illegal to ride an elephant on the motorway, so it would be using A and B roads only.  Is riding an elephant the same as riding a horse in the eyes of the law?

Comment: I would love to know the background to this. Also, I feel that this is a question for the local authorities, not for random people on the internet.

Comment: An elephant walks at about 4.5mph.  Warrington to Peterborough is about 135 miles.  That's about 30 hours of travel, plus breaks for rest / food / water.  Purely from a matter of animal welfare, I would **strongly** suggest hiring a truck.

Comment: Does the "H" in your name stand for Hannibal?